# How to schedule R script in crontab on Mac Snow Leopard?

Tags: r, cron

So I have an R file that I would like to schedule to run every 10 minutes. I have created an entry for the file in crontab through the Terminal (using crontab -e). As so:

```
*/10    *       *       *       *       root    /Users/A/Documents/code/r/r_file.r
```

When I run the commands in the console it executes as designed and I can verify records in the database. However, with this cron setup I am not getting the end result.

I did get the following error message:

```
/bin/sh: root: command not found
```

I am sure this is a total rookie question as I do not have much experience with crontab. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `Rscript` is in your path?  More importantly, is it in path of the user running the commamd, here root?  (Also consider running the command as you).

If so, try

```
*/10 * * * *      yourlogin    Rscript /Users/..../file.R
```

Test your understanding of `crontab` with a simpler job that just stores timestamps, maybe

```
*/10 * * * *      yourlogin    date > /tmp/testcrontab.txt
```

Once you have that mastered, run a simple R script and then move on to your real script.

Answer (score 2):

The "root" part of you crontab line is what's screwing you up. When you use `crontab -e`, you should not specify the user because all the commands run as your current user (i.e. the user you are logged in as when you run `crontab -e`).

Also, you should always use full paths in your crontab.

The cron line should look like this:

`*/10 * * * * /path/to/Rscript /Users/A/Documents/code/r/r_file.r`

Comment: No, the `root` (ie user) part is required when you edit `/etc/crontab` directly rather than going via `crontab -e`.  These are simply two alternatives.  Personally, I have my user jobs in `/etc/crontab` too.

Comment: Right. But he says he used `crontab -e`.

Comment: Hello, can someone provide me an example of a /path/to/Rscript. I can't get it to work and my guess is that I am using something wrong for there. Thanks

Comment: I got it working. Maybe this helps someone, in my case I just had to write Rscript without a path